# Getting values from Kendo Grid row on DetailExpand

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have got a Kendo Grid and I want to access the data from the row whose detail I expanded. For testing purposes, I have this:

```
function detailExpand(e)
{
    var aux = e.sender.MyModelId;
    var aux2  = this.MyModelId;
    ...
```

But none of those variables have the `MyModelId` in it.

[image: print]

I have inspected it and I can't find the model properties unless inside the `e.sender._data[index-here]` but I don't know the index of the row whose detail I've expanded.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

e.sender.dataItem(e.masterRow).MyModelId

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-detailExpand
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-dataItem

For the record, you should try to avoid using methods starting with an underscore (_). I believe kendo uses the underscore to show it's an internal method (a "private"). Unexpected behavior could occur.

Comment: This completely fixes the problem i was having of a grid within a grid within a grid. I am now able to correctly get the parent data no matter how deep in I am (unlike other stackoverflow answers that only work for 1 level deep)

Comment: Thanks @Pluc that's great

Comment: Great, this is what I was looking for a long time!